# How to show a "static" html page in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to display a "static" html page upon clicking a component of my page, on my Meteor app. This page only function is to display information, and I don't want the user interacting with it at all. The desired functionality is that I have a "Click to see an example" label (actually a link) in one of my forms that will display a "mock snapshot" of that same form with pre-poulated information, as an example of the kind of information that is expected on each field.

Of course this app is using templates (including a *navbar*, a footer, etc.), so upon clicking that link on the associated `Template.XYZ.events` I'm using `window.open` to display that "mock page" (preferably as a new window instead of a new tab).

The problem is that I forgot that Meteor is an opinionated tool and has its own way of [structuring the app and loading files](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) so that "static" page, when is displayed in the new window, has the navbar and the footer too (and I believe that this will confuse some users that will try to follow the process in this new window).

I tried using a template to show this static page, in which case I get the navbar and footer and other components common to all pages. I tried with a "raw" html page, but due to Meteor's way of loading files I just get this html page loaded and displayed everywhere too. I though about moving it to a "private" directory, but then I'm not sure how to reach it (I have used [Assests](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets), but to reach stuff from server side).

How can I display this "disconnected" page via `window.open` on my Meteor app?

I'm aware that Meteor is aimed to build amazing "single page" sites, so I guess that this behavior might be a little bit against the `Embrace the ecosystem` principle. I don't know if what I want is even possible in this platform, and if it is so, how.

Comment: What router are you using?  If you're using Iron Router, you probably defined a layout template for the entire application, correct?

Comment: @StephenWoods, yes, I'm in fact using Iron Router, so I call this example page as `{{ pathFor 'exampleXYZ' }}`, being that the name of the html file that contains the template. Of course there's also a `this.route('exampleXYZ')`. My latest approach is indeed trying to play around this, but I was hoping that the question could remain open about how to do this with a "plain vainilla" Meteor project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using Iron Router. It allows you to define different layout for different route (it maybe solves the proble here). This is a little demo example of how to do this.

> HTML

```
<template name="hello">
  <button class="sayHello">Click Me</button>
  {{> sayGoodbye}}
</template>

<template name="sayGoodbye">
<button class="goodbye">
        Goodbye
</button>
</template>

<template name="ApplicationLayout">

    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="mainarea">
    This is a first layout.<br>
        {{>yield "main"}}
    </div>

    </div><!-- / container -->

</template>

<template name="homeLayout">

    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="mainarea">
        This is a second layout.<br>
        {{>yield "main"}}
    </div>

    </div><!-- / container -->


</template>
```

> Router.js file in the lib folder

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout',
    layoutTemplate: 'homeLayout',
});


Router.route('/', function(){
    this.layout('ApplicationLayout');
    this.render("hello", {to: "main"});
});

Router.route('/different', function(){
    this.layout('homeLayout');
    this.render("hello", {to: "main"});
});
```

So, basically you can just define a root for the static page. Then, code its layout as a layout template and use the `this.layout()` function to show it.

Comment: Thank you. I had a `layoutTemplate` on my IronRouter configuration, working as a 'default' and I forgot I can add/use more. This worked for me (although I left my configuration as it was and just use a different layout without footer, navbar and other elements for the special page/route). +1 for now. I'll leave some time for other to provide a solution (see if someone comes with an interesting different approach w/o IronRouter) and then choose a 'best answer'. Thank you again.